# React-native application not opening after yarn eject

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I started my small **React-Native** Project, by using create-react-native-app "appName", so this file will gave some boilerplate, and i used this with expo, after i completed my small app, now i need native code, So i googled and i found to make this create-react-native-app into react-native init project style, we need to use **yarn eject**. So i did that, but after doing this i got addition two folders in my project called "android" and "ios" its fine, But if i run my project now from my terminal.

react-native run-android

The app doesnot load into my mobile device, nor showing any error.